# Check if jquery function name is unique (and html id)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC ASP.net project (in Visual Studio), which becomes bigger and bigger.

Is there a way to check if a jquery function is unique ? For example, I have a `function Foo()` and I would like to know if there isn't another function with the same name and signature.

In addition, same question for an HTML id in all pages.

The point here is not to perform a search. Imagine you have about 300 functions and you want to make your code safer. In this case you have to perform a search on 300 functions, not imaginable.

I was thinking about C#, you cannot have 2 methods with the same signature. I would like to know (as it is allowed in jquery) if there was a trick or a tool to identify such a case.

Comment: You can search simply. Ctrl+F. type function Foo() and select entire solution.

Comment: If this is a VS question, does it not belong in SuperUser?

Comment: mplungjan, what do you mean by `SuperUser` ?

Comment: @JyothishBhaskaran cntrl-shift-F would be quicker and not need to change the scope back and forth.

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=visual+studio

Comment: If it's *not* a VS question, then you should know that javascript doesn't do overloads, the second definition would overwrite the first so there would only ever be one.

Comment: @mplungjan that's right. I missed it.

Comment: Pass it through `jslint` - a quick test shows that it will tell you if there's a `Redefinition of 'funcName' from line` on your duplicate.  You can use an online tool: https://www.jslint.com/ (or a plugin to VS/R#).   Take *most* of what jslint tells you under advisory, but it is ideal to handle your specific use case.

Comment: Finding duplicate `id=` within Razor will not be so simple at the source level.  Checking once the page has rendered is a case of listing all IDs and then checking how many have more than one match.

Comment: For completeness: `$("*").map(function(i,e) { try { return (e.id !== "" && $("#" + e.id).length > 1) ? e.id : null } catch { return null; }})`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is searching on your editor and the hotkey depends on your editor. If you use:

IntelliJ, Visual Studio Code: CTRL + SHIFT + F (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html)

Sublime Text, Notepad++, 2017: CTRL + F (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-in-files?view=vs-2017)

Comment: *To cancel a Find operation, press Ctrl + Break.* - not to initiate a search

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I know how to do a search. I will edit my question.